How do I create user flow performace tests with Lighthouse and Playwright?
I've seen documentation on creating user flows with lighthouse and puppeteer.  Here's what I've tried to mimic in Playwright to no avail:
https://imeugenia.medium.com/user-flow-web-performance-testing-for-desktop-devices-5b8ef3294b41
Is there a way to do this in Playwright?
Here's an example of how I've tried to mimic a userflow test using Playwright:


import { expect, test } from '@playwright/test';
import playwright from 'playwright';
import { audit } from '../utils/audit';

test.describe('Top 20 sites', () => {

  test(`Ligthouse User Journey performance test`, async () => {
    test.slow();
    const browser = await playwright['chromium'].launch({
      args: ['--remote-debugging-port=9222'],
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Find Hotels' }).click();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    // Create a new page in a pristine context.
    const searchPage = await context.newPage();

    const results = await audit(searchPage, 'userFlow')
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    // expect(results.lhr.categories.performance.score, `${'https://www.marriott.com/default.mi'} fell below the minimum threshold`).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(.30);
  });
});



I get this error:


Error: require() of ES Module /projects/SITE-PERF/node_modules/lighthouse/core/index.js from /projects/SITE-PERF/node_modules/playwright-lighthouse/src/task.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /projects/SITE-PERF/node_modules/playwright-lighthouse/src/task.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

 at ../utils/audit.ts:7

   5 |
   6 | export const audit = async (page: Page, reportDir: string) => 
>  7 |     playAudit({
     |                ^
   8 |         page: page,
   9 |         config: lighthouseDesktopConfig,
  10 |         thresholds: thresholds,

    at Object.<anonymous> (projects/SITE-PERF/utils/audit.ts:7:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/projects/SITE-PERF/tests/user-flow.spec.ts:5:14)

Error: No tests found.
Make sure that arguments are regular expressions matching test files.
You may need to escape symbols like "$" or "*" and quote the arguments.



